# Android bluetooth: Device specific connection issues

Tags: android, bluetooth

The problem is the following: I'm working on an Android project at the moment that involves the connection of two Android devices. I've got the connection and data transfer working with the guidelines of http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html but my application only works with two specific devices, the Sony Xperia LT22i (Android 4.0.4) and the Samsung Galaxy S Plus (Android 2.3.6).

When I try it on other Smartphones, they can successfully connect and they receive the test-byte '1', with which I check if the connection is working. But when the actual data transmission starts, they don't receive anything and there is no Exception thrown.

I can add the code if needed, but it's the same as on the mentioned Android Developers page, with a few app-specific changes. Has anyone had this problem or knows how to fix it? Thanks in advance.